# Dynamically add corner ribbon to an image request (C#)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-web-api, webforms

Has anyone seen a library or NuGet perhaps that adds a corner ribbon to an image request. I am thinking something like the Re-sizer package which changes the image size to that of your parameters (i.e. href="../image.img?height=100&width=100" )
This library is awesome and I would love to find a way to do the same thing with CSS/bootstrap ribbons. Since I am building an API that would serve both an app and website (and ribbons would be required for both), having a solution within the API would be awesome. Thoughts? Has anyone seen a possible solution already created?

Comment: It's pretty straight forward, you would take the image and load it into a Bitmap then add the corners and you're done. Here's an example using WinForms: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/103502-border-around-an-image/

Comment: Nice! I appreciate the quick answer. I like this, however the banner would be skewed if the image was not the same size always. I'm thinking of possibly drawing a shape dynamically according to the width/height, Would be a lot of drawing though I imagine